# How to disable CTRL keyboard in WPF DataGrid

Tags: datagrid

I have a datagrid where in i want to prevent user from CTRL Key press.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/AB17035_ZLT_Client;component/Images/bum_big.PNG"
                                Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="0.05" />
        </Border.Background>
        <DataGrid Name="PlanGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16" RowHeight="30" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            SelectionMode="Extended" 
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
            Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PlanDataView, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Cursor="Arrow" AllowDrop="True">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand"></KeyBinding>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="PlanGrid_Loaded" TargetObject="{Binding}"></ei:CallMethodAction>                        
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>                
        </DataGrid>
```

If user tries for CTLR key press it should not work on wpf datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled and found the answer for it. Below is the piece of code to prevent from ctrl key press.

```
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {                
                e.Handled = true;                
                MessageBox.Show("CTRL Key is not allowed");
            }
        }
```

also add this function "PreviewKeyDown" to load event of data grid as below:

```
public void PlanGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
           planDatagrid.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(PreviewKeyDown);               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Behind

```
  InitializeComponent();
 dvSalesEntryDataGrid.PreviewKeyDown += Datagrid_PreviewKeyDown;
```

and Methods

```
private void Datagrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Key == Key.RightCtrl||e.Key==Key.LeftCtrl)
            {
             e.Handled = true;
            }
```

}